# SSRS int parameter passes to sub report as text

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2012 and I'm trying to pass an integer value (ItemKey) from my first report to a parameter (prmItemKey) in a second report that opens in a new window.

The second report opens up as expected, but instead of receiving the passed value it receives the name of the field as text.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://rd-sql.rossdown.local/ReportServer?%2fSupportFolder%2fItem+Details&rs:Command=Render&prmItemKey=Fields!ItemKey.Value'))"
```

The parameter `prmItemKey` is expecting an integer, and the report returns a `type mismatch error` when it receives `Fields!ItemKey.Value` as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect its actually passing the text 'Fields!ItemKey.Value' in your querystring to your **Linked** report.

You'll need to expand your `Fields!ItemKey.Value` before you put it in the querystring

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://rd-sql.rossdown.local/ReportServer?" &
  "%2fSupportFolder%2fItem+Details&rs:Command=Render&prmItemKey=" & 
  Fields!ItemKey.Value & "'))"
```

[edit]  added clarification to make the solution easier to find. (thanks Dan)

Comment: This answer is right, but just to clarify a bit: you should have the 'Fields!ItemKey.Value' outside the double quotations denoting the URL string such that the report evaluates it as the value of the ItemKey field rather than just passing the literal string, like so: `="javascript:void(window.open('http://rd-sql.rossdown.local/ReportServer?%2fSup‌​portFolder%2fItem+Details&rs:Command=Render&prmItemKey=" & Fields!ItemKey.Value & "'))"`

Comment: Trubs and Dan, thank you so much for the help! Scholars and gentlemen, the both of you!